# How to fix XSS issues in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, xss

I have a form which is sent to a URL, This server stores the fieids in a database and sends out email messages then posts back a success page to the browser.  The form works in Firefox but in IE8 the data is saved, the email messages are sent, but the success page is blocked. How do I disable the XSS filter or rewrite my form to avoid this issue.  I don't understand why it is blocked but If I comment out the user information section of the form it works.

I'm new to Javascript and HTML and I don't understand most of what I read about the XSS filter.  I inhererted this code so I just don't know the right way to code these forms.

Actually there are two forms generated with a javascript and submitted to the server.  the first form submited in the code below has the XSS issue the second form which is very similar works prefectly.

```
function doSubmit()
{
if (!validateForm())
    return false;

if (confirmForm())
{
    generateForm_code();  //builds first form 
    clearUndefinedFieldsInForm("form_generated_code");
            document.form_generated_code.target="frame_code";
    document.form_generated_code.method="post";
             document.form_generated_code.action= "http://their.server.com/servlet/UFO?001=1";
    document.form_generated_code.submit();


    generateForm(); //builds second form 
    clearUndefinedFieldsInForm("form_generated");
    document.form_generated.target="frame_generated";
    document.form_generated.method="post";      
    document.form_generated.action = "http://their.server.com/servlet/UFO?002=1";
    document.form_generated.submit();
}       
}
```

The their.server.com sends back the reply

```
<body>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<html>
<script language="javascript">
  location.replace("http://my.server.com/successback.html");
</script>
</html>
</body>
```

My successback.html

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>SUCCESS BACK</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
parent.successbackHandler();
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

This section counts the returned forms and sends the true success message once it receives two replies.  But since it just receives one reply it never displays the reallyfinished.html page.

```
totalPostPages= 2

function successbackHandler()
{
totalPostPages --;
if(totalPostPages == 0)
{
    MaskDialog.hide();
    totalPostPages= 2
    window.location="reallyfinished.html";
}
}
```

Comment: I get a yellow bar at the top of the broswer window which states "Internet Explorer modified this page to prevent a potential cross-scripting attack..."

Comment: And you can’t change the response of ‘their server’, right?

Comment: Actually, I can change the response of their server.

Comment: Then try an HTTP redirect instead.

Comment: If you’re using Servlet, try [HttpServletResponse.sendString](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect\(java.lang.String\)) (at best with [status code](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus\(int\)) 303).

Comment: I'm not using Java in my code but I changed the server response to <body> <head> <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://my.server.com/successback.html"> </head> <html> but it still didn't work.

Comment: Then what are you using to process the posted data server-sided?

Comment: Yes, the server-side uses Java but I don't control the server-side. I just submit the response back though a web form on their site. I didn't know if it would accept Java but I knew it accepted HTML so I tried the meta tag. I'll try the servlet you suggested.

Comment: I wasn't able to get the servlet to work but I commented out some code and it worked well enough to test it.  Thanks for your help Gumbo.